# Change the sql query based on which checkboxes that are checked

Tags: mysql, vb.net, if-statement, checkbox, dynamic

So i am making this program, where you can register and also edit the employees information. At the moment one specific query runs if one specific checkbox is checked, but this means that you can only change one column of information at a time.

What i want is a dynamic editing system, where the query changes depending on which checkboxes that are selected, so i can change all the columns at one time.

[Here is the design with textboxes, and comboboxes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcxbE.jpg)

[Here is the code behind the Run button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igQEP.jpg)

Any help or pointers are more then welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Friendly advice: avoid posting links. Try as much as you can to add relevant code *here*. People will not visit links. You'll get downvoted or closed as off-topic. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlexTartan Thanks for the tip! But i dont have enough reputation to post images directly in the post right now(Need 10 reputation).

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, you should use a multi conditional update like this:

```
update table 
set firstname=(if "checkBoxValue1","firstNameInputValue",firstName),
lastname=(if "checkBoxValue2","lastNameInputValue",lastname)
where id="idvalue"
```

Comment: So this is the query right? 
So it should all be inside " "? 
Shouldnt it be "checkboxvalue1.checked?

Comment: it should get you true or false, it´s just that i dont exactly know how you call the  variables, but to be more specific, the names between " " are variables.